# Couldn't find toolkit reference (System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit & System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, silverlight-toolkit

I'm working on Silverlight project, which has done in few months back. When project is loaded, I've seen some of the references are missing. I tried to add it from assembly, but couldn't find any details.

[image: Capture]

I've already installed the both Silverlight SDK 5 & Silverlight_Developer (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28359).

Can someone help me to sort out this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be related with the Project framework version.
In project properties, try changing the framework version (the the one matching Silverlight SDK).